# Please check my sponsor letter for my US girlfriend

Tags: visas

There's only seven days until she comes. She's already been in the UK for under six months at the start of 2017 then waited six months to come back again for three months. We haven't applied for a visa (we didn't need to but it would have been wise) for her but I've written this letter. Please take a look and see what you think. Thank you.

> 12th January 2018
>
> **My name address and phone number**
>
> The Entry Clearance Officer
>
> Dear Sir or Madam
>
> Entry clearance sponsor letter for **her name, date of birth, passport
>   number and address.**
>
> I am writing in support of an entry clearance for **her name** . She
>   intends to visit me for an holiday of 82 days from January 13th 2018
>   until 5th of April 2018. We met online a year ago and then starting an
>   online relationship in July 2017. This will be our first time meeting.
>
> I am willing to sponsor her visit and pay all the necessary travelling
>   cost and any other expenses that she might incur during her stay in
>   the UK.
>
> I have developed and strong bond with her while chatting on skype (We
>   both have logs if you wish to see them) and would like to travel
>   together around my **local county name**. My disability known as
>   Postural Tachycardia Syndrome causes my heart rate to increase by
>   around 15-35bpm which can lead to dissociative disorders such as
>   derealization, depersonalization and Clouding of consciousness (Brain
>   fog) so I will need to sit or lay down often to limit or avoid these.
>   I also have fatigue so some days I will not be able to go out on trips
>   and will need to rest. This leads to the reason why I have asked her
>   to apply for an three month trip in the UK. Before meeting her I would
>   simply stay in my bed room playing on my computer waiting for doctor
>   appointments. Being with her will motivate me to do activities
>   together which will increase my confidence, mental and physical
>   health.
>
> I'd like to travel with her to towns, villages, ruins, castles and
>   churches. We have plans to visit **I list many areas around my which
>   people would like to visit (I will have a list of areas we will visit
>   should you wish to see) < Should I include this?**
>
> **Other reasons (incentives to return back home after visit) Still needs more information?**
>
> She lives with her mother, brother, and aunt. She is very close to
>   them all, especially her grandmother whom unfortunately passed away
>   this past December. She has been helping her family cope with the loss
>   and fully intends to return and be there for them after the duration
>   of her visit.
>
> **Being able to support Put down the weekly cost of her stay (I still need to work this out). Make them aware of her insurance = I have
>   bought her adequate insurance for her total stay here.**
>
> I am presently on disability and have been since I was 18 years old
>   (I'm 33 years old now) I started receiving Incapacitated Benefit and
>   then moved onto Employment and Support Allowance. Starting around June
>   2015 I also went onto Personal Independence Payment as well. I have a
>   bank balance of £5,347.63 as of 31th Dec 2017 and receive EESA £234
>   fortnightly and PIP £331 every month (Please view attached redacted
>   bank statement (Bank's recommendation). I have duplicate bank
>   statements on me which date back a year in the waiting area if you
>   wish to view them and they are not redacted) I currently live at home
>   with my mother and father in a three-bedroom home that they own. My
>   father has given his permission for her three-month stay and will be
>   with me if you wish to ask him yourself. My girlfriend would have more
>   than enough space to live comfortably with us during her visit.
>
> I give you my full assurance that that I can support, maintain and
>   accommodate my girlfriend without any recourse to public funds
>   (attached is Sponsorship Declaration) I have bought her adequate
>   insurance for her total stay here which a copy will be included with
>   this letter. You have my word that she will return to the United
>   States after her stay with me on the 5th of April.
>
> I would therefore be grateful if you can kindly issue the clearance to
>   her.
>
> Should you require any additional information please do not hesitate
>   to contact me on **my number** or my dad **his number**. I will be in
>   the waiting area with my dad if you'd like to talk to me/us.
>
> Thank you.
>
> Yours faithfully
>
> **My name**

Would you say this is ok so far? Thank you.

---

I've amended the letter;

12th January 2018

My name address and phone number

The Entry Clearance Officer

Dear Sir or Madam

Entry clearance sponsor letter for her name, date of birth, passport number and address.

I am writing in support of an entry clearance for her name She intends to visit me for an holiday of 82 days from January 11th 2018 until 5th of April 2018. We met online a year ago and then starting an online relationship in July 2017. This will be our first time meeting.

I am willing to sponsor her visit and pay all the necessary travelling cost and any other expenses that she might incur during her stay in the UK.

We plan to visit attractions around I list my two closest counties

Estimation of her weekly cost which I will bear is £80-100 pounds. This includes rent, food and bus tickets.

I am presently on the benefits Employment and Support Allowance and Personal Independence Payment. I have bank balance of £5,347.63 as of 31th Dec 2017 and receive EESA £236 fortnightly and PIP £332.40 monthly. I have unredacted duplicate bank statements dating back a year if you wish to view them. I currently live at home with my mother and father in an three bedroom home which they own. My father has given his permission for her total stay and will be with me if you wish to confirm this. My girlfriend would have more than enough space to be comfortably with us during her visit.

I give you my full assurance that that I can support, maintain and accommodate Her name without any recourse to public funds. I have bought her insurance for her total stay which a copy will be included with this letter.

I would therefore be grateful if you can kindly issue the clearance to her.

Should you require any additional information please do not hesitate to contact me on my number or my dad his number.. I will be in the waiting area with my dad if you'd like to talk to me/us.

Thank you. Yours faithfully My name

What do you think please?

Comment: Trouble is, you give your word that she'll return to the US. What will you do if she says no? How will you make her?

Comment: Yeah good point. It doesn't carry much weight does it. Cheers.

Comment: You said she was in the UK before--but in the letter it's your first time meeting in person?

Comment: Yeah she was with her ex then =)

Comment: I've edited it as you've asked Newton and deleted the answer I place. Cheers.

Comment: I've updated the letter. Please tell me what you think. Thank you.

Comment: @quackstar84 **Do not** write "entry clearance officer" as that means visa officer, but "Border Force officer"

Comment: @quackstar84 Also, you're wrong that it "would've been wise" to get a visa. Absolutely no point whatsoever seeing as she hasn't had past immigration-related issues in the UK

Comment: Cheers coke. I've changed that. we've been a touched worried that she already been in the UK for six months and now she's coming again after waiting six months for three months again. She has given up her job and has around $1300 so that is why i'm worried and gone to the trouble of hours of results. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I personally think your letter is a bit too verbose and may work against you; a sponsor letter should state the following:

1. Your details and status in the UK, and evidence thereof. For example, if you are a UK citizen, your passport details and copy.
2. Where the visitor will be staying. If staying with you, evidence that such an arrangement is allowed. For example, you can provide a deed to your house, or rental agreement showing that you are authorized to live at that address, etc. If you are living with your parents, then their details should also be included.
3. Evidence of your ability to financially bear the cost and not have it be a burden. This would usually mean salary or bank statements showing income - in your case I am not sure if your parents will also be contributing (financially) towards the costs if so they should also provide their details.
4. The details of the sponsored party, such as their full legal name, and possibly passport copy as well.
5. The nature of your relationship.
6. Their itinerary (arrival / departure details) - ideally with a copy of the return ticket if available.

You should **not include** the following:

1. An assurances and guarantees on your part (above and beyond the financial costs); simply because these are ineffective.
2. Any justifications (such as why she would go back) - this is part of the landing interview that the Border Force officer will do and it may sound like you are doing this on her behalf.
3. Any irrelevant personal details; such as your disability, etc. these are seen as superfluous and may be seen as a distraction to hide or misrepresent something else; **unless material to the nature of the visit**. She is visiting you and together you are going to tour the country. The fact that your disability makes the trip longer does not have a bearing on the granting of entry.

Comment: Goodnees Burhan. Thank you for a detailed reply. When it comes to the immigration officer interviewing her for information. Can they also interview me when I go to pick her up and see original copies? Or do I need to photocopy all the infomation for her to give them? I want to redact sensitive information she has about me but allow the OI to see the originals from me if need be. 
1.So I should take a photo copy of my passport and send her a copy? 
2.Ok my parents own our house but i'm not sure if we have a copy of the deed. If we do I'll take it with me or photocopy it for her.

Comment: 3.I'm going to be giving her a redact upto date bank statement and have my original for them to see.

4.She'll have her passport with her to show the IO

5.We're in a online relationship.

6. She will have a copy of her return ticket.

Replies to not recommended to include;

Yes i've been wondering about this part. Thank you

Excellent. This is why I asked this question. It makes sense that she needs to explain this herself to them.

Thank you so much. You've really helped me Burhan. I appreciate your time.

Comment: You have to understand the primary deciding factor is the landing interview. Your documents are just secondary and may only be used to verify statements. For example, the ECO might ask your friend on how she plans to fund the trip. She can say that you are bearing the costs, and she also as access to funds from her savings etc. The ECO will call you to ask if you are expecting someone and may visit you in the arrivals area (you are not authorized to visit the secure area where your friend will be). As she was previously granted entry, she would be familiar with the process.

Comment: Excellent thank you very again Burhan. You give clear and useful advice.

Comment: @quackstar84 The one error is the usage of the term ECO, which is **wrong**. ECO means visa officer - the officer you are addressing is a Border Force officer